# Is there any type of app that trains my english skills?

Tags: english, grammar

I like to write some more in english and for that I want to improve my vocabulary (and overall grammar skills). Is there an app that focuses on teaching new words and explains their meaning? I know that reading books helps a lot too (already doing that) but I'd like to have something that really focuses on the learning aspect. Not sure if something like Babble is good for that since I don't want to go through a tedious beginner session to get to the harder part.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on [ell.se].

Comment: @Keelan I doubt this question would fit in the English site

Comment: @tac perhaps, I'm not a member there. There is also [languagelearning.se] (I'm not a member there either). But it definitely does not fit here.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.